# Connecting Frontend application with Backend via AWS ECS Service Discovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, consul, aws-fargate, service-discovery

I have a web application that consists of Frontend (built on ReactJS) and Backend (built on Python).

Frontend: I have created a ECS Fargate service and attached aws application load balancer.

Backend: I have created a ECS Fargate service and attached ECS Service discovery.

Now, when I try to make request to the backend via service discovery, the response from backend never came. Here my frontend code snippet:

```
axios.get("http://be.be:5000/", {"abc":"bcd"})
                    .then(response => {
                        alert(response['data'])
                        console.log(response)
                        return response.data
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.log(error)

                    })
```

Here, 'be.be' is the URL provided by AWS ECS service discovery. Instead of **"http://be.be:5000/"** if I put public of the task like this: **"http://public-ip:5000/"** it works perfectly.

[Note: I have created an ec2 server on the same VPC and tried to **dig +short http://be.be**, it works perfectly as well]

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 2):

You **can't use** service discovery (SD) names over the Internet from your front-end. They are only usable within a VPC, not from the outside. This is because SD uses only **private IP** addresses which can't be used over the internet. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/service-discovery.html):

> The DNS records created for a service discovery service **always** register with the **private IP address** for the task, rather than the public IP address, even when public namespaces are used.

For traffic over the internet, you have to use your load balancer.

Comment: Okay, but my Frontend service is running inside the VPC.

Comment: @DeependraDangal Can you clarify what do you mean? It is internal website, never accessed from the internet?

Comment: it's not an internal application. It will be accessed from the internet, but only the frontend will be accessed from internet. I don't want to expose the backend over load balancer, because it is public, am I right?

Comment: @DeependraDangal You wrote that the code `axios.get(...)` is in your frontend. For me, this means that it is executing in a user's browser, i.e. its client side code.

Comment: any alternative of load balancer? because, I don't want to use load balancer. Also, I have heard of some third party service discovery tools like: consul, will it work?

Comment: and one more thing, If i use VPN, does it work with service discovery?

Comment: @DeependraDangal VPN will work because it will use private IP addresses between your external network and your vpc. But it will not be a publicly accessible website. For fargate only load balancers can be used for ECS, unless you are fine with using non-static ip address of your task. You can move your website to EC2, e.g. elastic beanstalk, which does not require load balancer, or use ECS EC2, instead of fargate.

Comment: can you please explain this line: "use ECS EC2, instead of fargate" what does this mean?